# React toggle className on button click

Tags: reactjs

I wanna change my layout between grid and list with 2 buttons. I am very new to react, and I thought to use State, my button logic seems to work(when i console.log) but I don't know how to change div classNames based on State. I tried something but it doesnt work(see below). Whatever button I click grid or list my style changes but only for the first click, then nothing happens.

```
const Restaurants = () => {
    const [isGrid, layoutToggle] = useState({
        value: true
    });


    console.log(isGrid);

    return (
        <div className="restaurants">

            <button onClick={() => layoutToggle({ isGrid: true })}>
                Grid
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => layoutToggle({ isGrid: false })}>
                List
            </button>

            <div className={isGrid["value"] ? "layout-grid" : "layout-list"}>
                {restaurants.map(restaurant => (
                    <Restaurant/>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the button elements, You should the change the state with the value property not the isGrid property.

```
<button onClick={() => layoutToggle({ value: true })}>
   Grid
</button>
<button onClick={() => layoutToggle({ value: false })}>
   List
</button>
```

Comment: thanks man that was it. Is there a better way to use useState (name and value) for what i did?

Comment: The more simplified way is instead of using object we can directly use boolean value as state; const [isGrid, layoutToggle] = useState(true);
<div className={isGrid ? "layout-grid" : "layout-list"}>

Comment: ok but if i use const [isGrid, layoutToggle] = useState(true) how do i use layoutToggle() to set true or false?

Comment: onClick={() => layoutToggle(true)} // true or false based on the type of button